# How does the XML_COMPRESSION option work?

Tags: sql-server, xml, database-internals, compression

`XML_COMPRESSION` has recently gone GA in [Azure SQL Database](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/general-availability-of-xml-compression-for-azure-sql-database/ba-p/3888861)

I've been trying to find some details about how it works to understand the pros and cons and so far not found any specifics.

Trying the below on SQL Server 2022 ...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[XmlCompressionTest](
Id INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_XmlCompressionTest PRIMARY KEY  WITH (XML_COMPRESSION = ON),
Marker VARBINARY(6),
TestXml XML,
Compressed varbinary(MAX)
);

--https://codebeautify.org/generate-random-xml
DECLARE @XmlAsString NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'<root>
  <available>zoo</available>
  <flame>-1069239245.2026982</flame>
  <living>gather</living>
  <grandfather>
    <tell>
      <map>-1618074814</map>
      <to>2070665023</to>
      <amount>six</amount>
      <well>join</well>
      <wore>-920111498.4217186</wore>
      <question>176219184.84385443</question>
    </tell>
    <rain>floating</rain>
    <company>-2102390055.351131</company>
    <pole>better</pole>
    <fruit>amount</fruit>
    <wealth>aid</wealth>
  </grandfather>
  <breathe>you</breathe>
  <increase>-82882542.41709375</increase>
</root>';


INSERT [dbo].[XmlCompressionTest]
VALUES (0x7E7E7E7E7E7E, @XmlAsString, COMPRESS(@XmlAsString))

SELECT *, sys.fn_PhysLocFormatter(%%physloc%%)
FROM [dbo].[XmlCompressionTest]
```

And then running `DBCC PAGE` on the resultant page I see the following for the three variable length columns

[image]

`DBCC PAGE` reports that "TestXml" has a Length of 730 but physical length of 644, whereas the "Compressed" column has a length of 420. So [`COMPRESS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/compress-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) clearly wins on the basis of raw compression.

I see that the "TestXml" column (purple highlighted) appears to have some sort of header info with quite a few `0x00` - I assume this is potentially some sort of structure to speed up operations against the XML?

Anyone know the details of `XML_COMPRESSION` and its pros and cons vs

- No compression (i.e. are we trading off much here for the lower storage footprint?)
- Manual compression

?

Answer (score 4):

It was confirmed on the Azure announcements post that it uses [Xpress Compression Algorithm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-xca/a8b7cb0a-92a6-4187-a23b-5e14273b96f8) AKA LZXpress.

The documentation states

> This algorithm efficiently compresses data that contain repeated byte
> sequences. It is not designed to compress image, audio, or video data.
> **Between the trade-offs of compressed size and CPU cost, it heavily
> emphasizes low CPU cost**. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-xca/f3a46d03-dcec-4487-8ebe-cb19535a3a60)

and

> A protocol that depends on this algorithm would typically need to
> transfer significant amounts of data that cannot be easily
> precompressed by another algorithm having a better compression ratio. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-xca/d2da6f6a-31aa-48b7-a562-5e74c113c0f4)

This has a few variants.

`DBCC PAGE` with option `3` shows the uncompressed hex so I was able to [use that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6722480/73226) in a `C#` console app and experiment with different compression options. `COMPRESSION_FORMAT_XPRESS_HUFF | COMPRESSION_ENGINE_MAXIMUM` seemed to be a very close match.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
static extern uint RtlGetCompressionWorkSpaceSize(ushort CompressionFormat, out uint pNeededBufferSize, out uint Unknown);

[DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
static extern uint RtlCompressBuffer(ushort CompressionFormat, byte[] SourceBuffer, int SourceBufferLength, byte[] DestinationBuffer,
    int DestinationBufferLength, uint Unknown, out int pDestinationSize, IntPtr WorkspaceBuffer);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr LocalAlloc(int uFlags, IntPtr sizetdwBytes);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr LocalFree(IntPtr hMem);

const uint STATUS_SUCCESS = 0x00000000;
const uint STATUS_BUFFER_ALL_ZEROS = 0x00000117;
const uint STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER = 0xC000000D;
const uint STATUS_UNSUPPORTED_COMPRESSION = 0xC000025F;
const uint STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED = 0xC00000BB;
const uint STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL = 0xC0000023;

const ushort COMPRESSION_FORMAT_LZNT1 = 2;
const ushort COMPRESSION_FORMAT_XPRESS = 0x0003;
const ushort COMPRESSION_FORMAT_XPRESS_HUFF = 0x0004;

const ushort COMPRESSION_ENGINE_STANDARD = 0x0000;
const ushort COMPRESSION_ENGINE_MAXIMUM = 0x100;
const ushort COMPRESSION_ENGINE_HIBER = 0x0200;

var sourceHex =
    "dfff01b004f00472006f006f007400ef000001f801f00961007600610069006c00610062006c006500ef000002f80211037a006f006f00f7f0056600" +
    "6c0061006d006500ef000003f80311132d0031003000360039003200330039003200340035002e003200300032003600390038003200f7f0066c0069" +
    "00760069006e006700ef000004f8041106670061007400680065007200f7f00b6700720061006e006400660061007400680065007200ef000005f805" +
    "f004740065006c006c00ef000006f806f0036d0061007000ef000007f807110b2d003100360031003800300037003400380031003400f7f00274006f" +
    "00ef000008f808110a3200300037003000360036003500300032003300f7f00661006d006f0075006e007400ef000009f8091103730069007800f7f0" +
    "04770065006c006c00ef00000af80a11046a006f0069006e00f7f00477006f0072006500ef00000bf80b11122d003900320030003100310031003400" +
    "390038002e003400320031003700310038003600f7f0087100750065007300740069006f006e00ef00000cf80c111231003700360032003100390031" +
    "00380034002e0038003400330038003500340034003300f7f7f0047200610069006e00ef00000df80d110866006c006f006100740069006e006700f7" +
    "f00763006f006d00700061006e007900ef00000ef80e11122d0032003100300032003300390030003000350035002e00330035003100310033003100" +
    "f7f00470006f006c006500ef00000ff80f1106620065007400740065007200f7f00566007200750069007400ef000010f810110661006d006f007500" +
    "6e007400f7f0067700650061006c0074006800ef000011f8111103610069006400f7f7f0076200720065006100740068006500ef000012f812110379" +
    "006f007500f7f00869006e00630072006500610073006500ef000013f81311122d00380032003800380032003500340032002e003400310037003000" +
    "3900330037003500f7f7";

var sourceBytes = Convert.FromHexString(sourceHex);

var compressed = Compress(sourceBytes, COMPRESSION_FORMAT_XPRESS_HUFF | COMPRESSION_ENGINE_MAXIMUM);

Console.WriteLine("COMPRESSION_FORMAT_XPRESS_HUFF | COMPRESSION_ENGINE_MAXIMUM");
Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToHexString(compressed));

static byte[] Compress(byte[] buffer, ushort compressionFormat)
{
    var outBuf = new byte[buffer.Length * 6];

    uint ret = RtlGetCompressionWorkSpaceSize(compressionFormat, out var dwSize, out _);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    IntPtr hWork = LocalAlloc(0, new IntPtr(dwSize));
    ret = RtlCompressBuffer(compressionFormat, buffer,
        buffer.Length, outBuf, outBuf.Length, 0, out var dstSize, hWork);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    LocalFree(hWork);

    Array.Resize(ref outBuf, dstSize);
    return outBuf;
}
```

The first 24 bytes in the column value shown in the question are additional to this output (i.e. the `e8e8010078020000da0200006c020000da02000018000000`)

The remainder of the column value is very similar to the output of the C# above (same length and identical until a few bytes near the end)

"[The first 256 bytes indicate the bit length of each of the 512 Huffman symbols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-xca/c0244bfe-fd96-4fe5-97dd-39b9fc99b801)" - so that explains the section

```
74677676777788775777000000000000000000000000700786677776770000000000000000000000000000000000000070777777780877778777868778080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000008006000060040000800800000000000000870000000000000085070000000000007500000000000000778700000800000075870800000000008508008000000000568700000000000067768800000800008800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Given the overhead described above even if the XML is highly repetitive it is unlikely that the compression will save any space unless `DATALENGTH` of the XML is at least 300 bytes.

For values where the "compressed" form would be longer it just stores it uncompressed (as can be seen when changing `41` to `40` below)

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY  WITH (XML_COMPRESSION = ON),
TestXml XML
)

DECLARE @Xml XML = REPLICATE(N'<a>a</a>',41)
SELECT DATALENGTH(@Xml)

INSERT @T
VALUES (@Xml)

DECLARE @DynSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
(
SELECT  DbccCommand = CONCAT('DBCC TRACEON(3604);DBCC PAGE (2, ', file_id ,', ', page_id ,', 3);DBCC TRACEOFF(3604)')
FROM @T
cross apply sys.fn_PhysLocCracker(%%physloc%%)
)

EXEC (@DynSQL);
```

(Testing done on SQL Server 2022 - 16.0.4055.4 as we don't have access to this sort of thing in Azure!)